# HTML/CSS Background Image Shows Only Part of the Image Used

Tags: html, css, image, web, background

As the title states,
I am currently building a website, I am new to this and am trying to learn quickly. However this problem is quite frustrating as websites I have gone to do not help.

So at the moment I have an image that is of a high enough resolution that it should fill the screen easily. However when I load the HTML the image is zoomed in on the top right corner which is the only part visible. I have tried using "height" and "width" commands. I have also tried without them. I have attempted to use a `<div>` and `<body>`. However this problem still persists.

Another point is that when I use a `<div>` the whole screen is not filled, it still has a white border around what I believe is the `<div>`.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your CSS/html so we can have a look

Comment: Please provide a link to the page in question. Or better, paste your code right here.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support older browsers, it's not as simple as just adding one or two properties.

Read this: http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/

> Another point is that when I use a `<div>` the whole screen is not
>   filled, it still has a white border around what I believe is the
>   `<div>`.

You need this CSS to remove the default `margin` on `body`:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I would suggest you to make the width and height not in px but in % and secondly try setting the image using CSS

Read this Link, it will be more useful
http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/